# TypeScript declare class not found

Tags: typescript, intellisense, declaration

I have a class which extends the `EventEmmiter` class.

I want *IntelliSense* to show the different events you can listen to and help auto complete them, so I came up with this:

```
//Imports from index.ts
import {
    CommandContext,
    CommandErrorContext,
    CommandHandler
} from '../../';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

export class CommandHandler extends CommandHandlerEvents {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

}

export declare class CommandHandlerEvents extends EventEmitter {
    on(event: string, listener: Function): this;
    on(event: 'failure', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandErrorContext) => void): this;
    on(event: 'success', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandContext) => void): this;

    once(event: string, listener: Function): this;
    once(event: 'failure', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandErrorContext) => void): this;
    once(event: 'success', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandContext) => void): this;

    emit(event: string, args: any[]): boolean;
    emit(event: 'failure', args: [CommandHandler, CommandErrorContext]): boolean;
    emit(event: 'success', args: [CommandHandler, CommandContext]): boolean;
}
```

The code above does exactly what I want it to do, but when I create an instance of the `CommandHandler` class, it throws this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CommandHandlerEvents is not defined

I have read about people using interfaces to do the same thing, but when I change `CommandHandlerEvents` from a `declare class` to an `interface` the suggestions no longer show up on IntelliSense.

Example of the desired outcome: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aZSf.png)

Comment: Are `EventEmitter` or `CommandErrorContext` or `CommandContext` declared anywhere?

Comment: @recursive yes, I'll update the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `declare` a `class`, or use an `interface`, you're just adding things to the type system at *compile time*.  You're not adding anything at *runtime*.  If you look, nothing named `CommandHandlerEvents` gets emitted to JavaScript.  The `declare` keyword tells the compiler that the thing you're talking will exist at runtime because it will be provided by whatever runtime environment runs the code.

Do you want all uses of `EventEmitter` to have the specific hinting you're talking about?  If so, you can [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to add this type information:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
declare module 'events' {
  interface EventEmitter {
    on(event: string, listener: Function): this;
    on(event: 'failure', listener: (handler: EventEmitter, context: CommandErrorContext) => void): this;
    on(event: 'success', listener: (handler: EventEmitter, context: CommandContext) => void): this;

    once(event: string, listener: Function): this;
    once(event: 'failure', listener: (handler: EventEmitter, context: CommandErrorContext) => void): this;
    once(event: 'success', listener: (handler: EventEmitter, context: CommandContext) => void): this;

    emit(event: string, args: any[]): boolean;
    emit(event: 'failure', args: [EventEmitter, CommandErrorContext]): boolean;
    emit(event: 'success', args: [EventEmitter, CommandContext]): boolean;
  }
}

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
eventEmitter.once(...) // get hints
```

Or do you really want a class `CommandHandler` at runtime that is more specific than `EventEmitter`?  You could do that with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) too:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
export class CommandHandler extends EventEmitter { }
export interface CommandHandler {
  on(event: string, listener: Function): this;
  on(event: 'failure', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandErrorContext) => void): this;
  on(event: 'success', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandContext) => void): this;

  once(event: string, listener: Function): this;
  once(event: 'failure', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandErrorContext) => void): this;
  once(event: 'success', listener: (handler: CommandHandler, context: CommandContext) => void): this;

  emit(event: string, args: any[]): boolean;
  emit(event: 'failure', args: [CommandHandler, CommandErrorContext]): boolean;
  emit(event: 'success', args: [CommandHandler, CommandContext]): boolean;
}

const commandHandler = new CommandHandler();
commandHandler.once(...) // get hints
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, this is very useful, and fixed my problem.
I ended up using deceleration merging to achieve my goal.